# Cannot navigate using Prism IRegionManager in the DrawerHost drawer

Tags: wpf, mvvm, material-design, prism

I'm using `Prism` and `Material Design` frameworks, have xaml like this:

```
    <md:DrawerHost IsRightDrawerOpen="{Binding IsDrawerOpen}">
        <StackPanel>
            <Button
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                Command="{Binding Command}"
                Content="Click to open" />
            <!--<ContentControl prism:RegionManager.RegionName="Drawer" />-->
        </StackPanel>

        <md:DrawerHost.RightDrawerContent>
            <ContentControl
                Width="100"
                Height="100"
                prism:RegionManager.RegionName="Drawer" />
        </md:DrawerHost.RightDrawerContent>
    </md:DrawerHost>
```

I want to navigate to a stand-alone drawer view when the drawer is opened.

But, I got nothing when the drawer opened.

However, when I put the `ContentControl` in the `StackPanel`, I can navigate to the drawer view.

The view model code is:

```
    internal class MainWindowViewModel : BindableBase
    {
        private bool isDrawerOpen;
        private readonly IRegionManager regionManager;

        public bool IsDrawerOpen
        {
            get { return isDrawerOpen; }
            set { isDrawerOpen = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); }
        }

        public DelegateCommand Command { get; private set; }

        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {

        }

        public MainWindowViewModel(IRegionManager regionManager)
        {
            Command = new DelegateCommand(Action);
            this.regionManager = regionManager;
        }

        private void Action()
        {
            IsDrawerOpen = !IsDrawerOpen;
            regionManager.RequestNavigate("Drawer", "UserControl1");
        }
    }
```

And already registered the stand-alone drawer view in the `App.xaml.cs`.

I want to know how can I make the drawer view a single view, make it not coupling with the `DrawerHost` view.

I've googled for the above question, and I found another way to achieve this:

> Put a view in the `RightDrawerContent` directly, and make its view model an inner view model of `DrawerHost`'s view model.

But I still want to know why the Prism navigation not working.

Thanks for any help.